# How do I open an existing file in a floating window?

Tags: neovim, vim-windows, lua

For a plugin, I want to open an existing file situated in `lua/myPlugin/` in a floating window, so whatever the actual working directory is, this file is always the one to be opened. It sounded easy, but I'm definitely missing something.
So far I have:

```lua
local buf, win

local function open_win()
    buf = vim.api.nvim_create_buf(false, true)

    vim.api.nvim_buf_set_option(buf, "bufhidden", "wipe")

    local width = vim.api.nvim_get_option("columns")
    local height = vim.api.nvim_get_option("lines")

    local win_height = math.ceil(height * 0.8 - 4)
    local win_width = math.ceil(width * 0.8)

    local row = math.ceil((height - win_height) / 2 - 1)
    local col = math.ceil((width - win_width) / 2)

    local opts = {
        style = "minimal",
        relative = "editor",
        width = win_width,
        height = win_height,
        row = row,
        col = col,
        border = "rounded",
    }

    win = vim.api.nvim_open_win(buf, true, opts)
    vim.api.nvim_win_set_option(win, "cursorline", true)
end

local function view()
    vim.api.nvim_buf_set_option(buf, "modifiable", true)
    vim.cmd(":edit catalog.txt")
    vim.api.nvim_buf_set_option(0, "modifiable", false)
end

local function view_cat()
    open_win()
    view()
end

return {
    view_cat = view_cat,
}
```

Of course, the problem is in the `view()` function: I am using as a workaround `vim.cmd(":edit catalog.txt")` which doesn't work.

So far, everything I tried lead to have a blank floating window and a regular buffer opened with an empty `catalog.txt` file, even if `lua/myPlugin` folder is my working directory and/or if I'm calling the function from within the `lua/myPlugin` directory.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a solution:

In the `view()` function, in place of the `vim.cmd(":edit catalog.txt")` line:

```lua
local file_path = vim.api.nvim_get_runtime_file("myPlugin/lua/catalog.txt", false)[1]
vim.api.nvim_command("$read" .. file_path)
```

The `nvim_get_runtime_file({name}, {all})` function takes a pattern of the files to search for and a boolean (true: all the files found, false: only the first one). It returns a list of the absolute path of the found files.

The `nvim_command({cmd})` execute any command as if it was typed in the command line. The `read` command insert the given file below the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `vim.cmd(":edit catalog.txt")`
you could use `vim.cmd(":read catalog.txt")`

Comment: Welcome to Vi and Vim SE. Thank you for writing an answer. You could improve it by adding a little explanation how this solves the problem presented in the question. Thanks in advance.